# How do I create sandbox environments on Mac OSX for running different program / projects?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, sandbox, virtualization, osx-yosemite

How do I create sandbox environments on Mac OSX for running different program / projects?

Let me envision a scenario for you. Say, I want to achieve three things from my computer simultaneously:
1) Work on an open source project that requires a particular set of configurations such as GCC4.6, Python 2.6 etc. to run / test etc.
2) Work on another open source project which gives its full functionality when running GCC4.8 or greater, Python 3.x etc. to run / test etc.
3) Listen to iTunes in the background.

Now, configuring the environment for the first two things is not easy and messes things up. What is even more hard is finding an intersection of combinations that can run both.

I achieve this by running VMWare and creating a new virtual machine for each open source project - configuring it to work with the project's requirements. However, this is not scalable. Is there a better way to achieve sandboxing?
I have a 2.53 GHz dual core processor with 16GB memory.

Answer (score 1):

You might try Vagrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/ and install your Virtual Machine and work on that.

Further informations: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/why-vagrant/index.html

Hope it can be useful for you.

Comment: Does it save on memory/CPU usage compared to running a simple VM on say VMWare?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/584100/why-should-i-use-vagrant-instead-of-just-virtualbox